# How stable is canvas.toBlob() method in different browsers?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

There are many polyfills out there to convert the contents of a Canvas to a Blob. Before deciding to go with one of those, wanted to know the support of native method `canvas.toBlob()` on various browsers. How stable is the method in different browsers?? Couldn't find it on http://caniuse.com

Note: I am not looking for server side solutions or client-side polyfill based solutions. Interested in knowing about the stability of toBlob() API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated Feb 02, 2017: canvas.toBlob is supported in Chrome since 50 as well as in Opera (Blink).

At the moment of this writing the support for `toBlob()` is poor (major browsers only):

- **[Firefox has support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Browser_support)** <del>(as currently the only one)</del>
- <del>Chrome has intended support but there is currently an [unsolved issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67587) with it.</del>
- Internet Explorer 10-11 [support it using prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `msToBlob()` but returns only PNG
- <del>Safari has [an issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71270) with status "resolved/won't fix"</del>
- <del>Opera (Blink) has no support (method not present on canvas element)</del>
- Opera (old) has no support (method not present on canvas element)

None support `toBlobHD()` at this time (as with most of the HD suffixed methods).

Comment: canvas.toBlob is already supported in Chrome since version 50.